# Modelo de regressão Cox no R

Tags: r

Olá,

Estou tentando desenvolver uma Regressão Cox no R, mas consigo apenas uma reta com valores praticamente contínuos.

```
ano<- c(1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)

dado1<-c(117.6423,116.3174,120.5568,140.6938,172.2240,143.6083,140.9587,121.3517,155.5315,145.1981,127.4458,126.6509,133.8048,155.2666,174.8736,116.5824,130.3603,125.0611,124.0013,121.6166,130.8902,157.6512,119.2320,111.2832,144.9331,160.5658,125.3261,166.3949,145.1981)

dado2<-c(237.2314,226.8339,237.7374,246.8556,245.0277,226.8549,240.7147,242.8530,235.3038,243.4697,228.0853,237.0662,234.8285,233.6033,245.6090,237.1481,234.6894,239.9852,237.6996,234.6507,229.7693,239.0660,236.2122,243.6228,233.9454,242.9659,239.3584,242.5270,227.0022)

dado3<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

dados<-data.frame(cbind(ano,dado1,dado2,dado3))

require(survival)

curva <- coxph(Surv(dado1, dado3) ~ dado2, dados)
a<-summary(curva)

coef<-as.numeric(data.frame(a$coef[1]))

eixo1<-survfit(curva)$surv

eixo2<-survfit(curva)$time


cox<-eixo1^exp(coef*dados[6,3])

plot(eixo2,eixo1,type='S',col="red",ylim=c(0,1.1))    
lines(eixo2,cox,col="black",type='l',lwd=2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu esperaria um gráfico com as linhas mais próximas uma da outra, não assim tão distante e não também com a 'curva cox' resultado valores praticamente constantes (pouca variação).

Como corrigir o modelo de regressão Cox que fiz acima?

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Não sei se pode ajudar, mas em `Surv(dado1, dado3)`, não seria `ano` ao invés de `dado1`? Não sei o que significa `dado1` mas a função função `Surv()` pede tempo e evento como entradas.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta Willian Vieira!
Tentei fazer do jeito que sugeriu, mas não funcionou. Ficou a reta vermelha na diagonal do gráfico e a reta preta com um pico no início (x0) e caindo a zero no final (x1).
A questão é que a variável ano, só me define o dado a cada ano mesmo. O que eu estou interessada em ver, seria o comportamento de d1 em relação ao d2. Que tecnicamente é o resultado esperado, que eles sejam semelhantes, independente de distâncias.

Comment: Qual foi o seu pensamento por trás dos códigos elaborados a partir do ajuste `coxph(Surv(dado1, dado3) ~ dado2, dados)`?  A função `coxph` já ajusta o modelo de riscos proporcionais de Cox, então não consegui entender o que você está chamando de "curva Cox".

Comment: Obrigada Rafael Cunha. Na verdade a expressão 1 - "curva <- coxph(Surv(dado1, dado3) ~ dado2, dados)" realmente, já estou ajustando o modelo, mas terei apenas as informações estatísticas, se assim podemos dizer.
O que eu quero com a expressão 2 - "cox<-eixo1^exp(coef*dados[6,3])" seria uma espécie de previsão, originando a minha reta preta. Essa etapa é aquela fórmula que se utiliza o coeficiente beta, encontrado na expressão 1. Encaminho o pdf, onde pode-se observar a fórmula, https://www.ime.usp.br/~acarlos/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=mae514_handout_cox_estimacao_testes.pdf.

Comment: @iara continuo sem identificar essa parte do código, mesmo analisando o pdf. O único local onde vi um exponencial de exponencial foi no 1º slide da página 7 do pdf. - que explica Taxas de Falhas Proporcionais. Quando li sua questão ("Eu esperaria um gráfico com as linhas mais próximas uma da outra...") entendi que você esperava comparar dois tipos de "indivíduos" e, vendo a parte de de Taxas de Falhas Proporcionais, também só consigo enxergar algo parecido. Só que os seus dados não tem distinção de indivíduos.

Comment: @RafaelCunha a fórmula que encontrou é exatamente a que eu me referia. Primeiro eu fiz a expressão 1, onde encontrei todos os coeficientes de cox ajustado, inclusive o beta. Em um segundo momento, aplicando a expressão 2, eu utilizo o coeficiente beta e calculo a fórmula do pdf. Posso ter me explicado mal, eu até poderia esperar uma longe da outra, mas que elas seguissem o ''desenho'' parecido, ou que seja, as duas linhas indo de 1,0 a 0 (ou próximo) e não como a linha preta, indo de 1,0 a 0,9. Eu tenho outros exemplos que 'funcionaram', mas esse eu queria entender o motivo de ter ficado assim

Comment: @RafaelCunha se preferir posso te mandar alguns artigos mais específicos do que pretendo fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Ao construir curvas de sobrevivência usando a saída da função `coxph`, deve-se considerar que essa função padroniza (variável menos a média dividido pelo desvio padrão) as covariáveis antes de ajustar o modelo. No código abaixo usei a função `scale` para realizar a padronização.

Além disso, note que o modelo de Cox considera em seu ajuste os tempos de falha distintos ordenados e no seu caso o 21 e o 22 são iguais. Falo, pois isso afetará a forma como estamos estimando a função de sobrevivência, uma vez que nestes casos são necessários definir alguns critérios para estimação da função supracitada. No seu problema considerei remover a informação da covariável na posição 22, por questões didáticas. Contudo, aconselho usar a estimativa da função `survfit` que já considera questões de empates e aspectos de mudança de escala das variáveis (você chamou de eixo1).
Abaixo apresento o código corrigido:

```
# Ano de observação:
ano<- c(1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)

# Variável dependente (tempo):
dado1<-c(117.6423,116.3174,120.5568,140.6938,172.2240,143.6083,140.9587,121.3517,155.5315,145.1981,127.4458,126.6509,133.8048,155.2666,174.8736,116.5824,130.3603,125.0611,124.0013,121.6166,130.8902,157.6512,119.2320,111.2832,144.9331,160.5658,125.3261,166.3949,145.1981)

# Variável independente (covariável):
dado2<-c(237.2314,226.8339,237.7374,246.8556,245.0277,226.8549,240.7147,242.8530,235.3038,243.4697,228.0853,237.0662,234.8285,233.6033,245.6090,237.1481,234.6894,239.9852,237.6996,234.6507,229.7693,239.0660,236.2122,243.6228,233.9454,242.9659,239.3584,242.5270,227.0022) 

# Indicador de censura (temos apenas falhas)
dado3<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

dados<-data.frame(cbind(ano,dado1,dado2,dado3))

require(survival)

curva <- coxph(Surv(dado1, dado3) ~ dado2, dados)
a<-summary(curva)

coef<-as.numeric(data.frame(a$coef[1]))

eixo1<-survfit(curva)$surv

eixo2<-survfit(curva)$time

# Estimativa da função de sobrevivência (excluindo a obseração 22):
cox <- eixo1 ^ exp(coef * scale(dado2[-22][order(dado1[-22])]))

plot(eixo2,eixo1,type='S',col="red",ylim=c(0,1.1))
lines(eixo2, cox,col="black",type='S', lwd=2)
```

Obs.: você pode excluir a informação da covariável da observação 21 e comparar os resultados. Ademais, pode substituir essa informação pela média dos valores observados para essa covariável nas posições 21 e 22 (`mean(dado2[c(21, 22)]`).